# Link on newsletter preview broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter, link-rot

The [link to the <s>Nyan Cat video</s> subscriptions page on stackexchange.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGFz5v_P2ug) on the newsletter preview is broken because the account was deleted.
[Example preview](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=codegolf.stackexchange.com)

I suggest that this link will be replaced by a <s>newer</s> older video, maybe [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY) one?

Comment: Sorry, but is it that important to you that we need this fixed? Seems there's more important stuff, but... :P

Comment: Don't listen to @hichris . There is nothing more important than this.

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging Then why didn't you already [status-completed] it, and fix it? :P

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging [here is alternative](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY), guess it's the same as the one that was removed...

Comment: @hichris123 I know. Super mega important. </sarcasm>. I just document it so it can be fixed whenever someone feels like doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This great injustice has been fixed.

I'm also happy to report that this is the first commit to any of the Stack Exchange repositories in 2014, I couldn't have asked for a better bug to set the mood for the year, thanks!

Comment: You people use git? Never knew.

Comment: We use Kiln which supports both mercurial and git. Most people use mercurial but the Careers team is moving over to be mostly git.