# Where should I ask questions about Careers 2.0?

Tags: support, jobs, site-recommendation

[Career 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) page is hosted under stackoverflow.com, that's why I am asking this question here.

Where can I ask non-technical questions about Careers 2.0? Stack Overflow is not a good choice. I am wondering if there is any specific site for this, or we may ask questions here?

Let me give an example by what I mean by non-technical.

For example, I was looking at [this job posting](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/34229/full-stack-web-developer-stack-exchange) from Stack Exchange, I found that they have a [Joel test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) score of 10 out of 12. How come Stack Exchange itself doesn't get a full score from the Joel test?

Comment: Click on the careers tag - are those the kinds of questions you're wanting to ask?

Comment: I see. Now, should we ask non-technical questions there? I will add an example to the question

Comment: Support questions about the Careers 2.0 site *itself* are on topic for Meta.

Comment: Because we clearly don't have testers or an up-to-date schedule.

Comment: Which is kind of strange to me. Anyways...

Comment: Well, schedule. Nope. Unimportant things like [a broken troll link in the newsletter preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214495/link-on-newsletter-preview-broken/) gets fixed soon. Other things not. And for tester? Ahh, well, [here is your new top bar, try it out on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support questions about the Careers 2.0 site itself are on-topic on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). (You may find some older posts about it here on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, but as of April 2014, those questions are now off-topic here).

Questions about specific companies are not on-topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network. Your sample question should be put to the company itself, not to the wider community. Use the Careers 2.0 functionality to contact the company directly instead:

[image: *Ask Stack Exchange a question* link]

Comment: I'd add the part about those questions being in the process of being closed; there are *tons* of these older questions laying around open, and we've had at least a couple cases where users have used these older open questions as "evidence" they can ask their question here.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that always happens. But eventually those questions will all have ended up closed and that part is them obsolete. It’s not that relevant to this answer in my view.